# Arrangement of variables in a class

Tags: c++, class, memory

Got a question for you all. Many of you will answer 'it makes no difference' but I'm somewhat adamant there is a difference due to the wording of the question:

'Which class uses the least amount of memory?'

They're asking for a singular answer - there must be one! I've had a chat with a previous Microsoft intern and he's adamant there is no answer.

Maybe some would care to offer their thoughts?

```
Which class uses the least amount of memory?

class A 
{
    float duration;
    char code;
    int count;
    bool enabled;
};

class B 
{
    float duration;
    int count;
    char code;
    bool enabled;
};

class C
{
    char code;
    int count;
    bool enabled;
    float duration;
};

class D
{
    bool enabled;
    float duration;
    char code;
    int count;
};
```

Comment: Sometimes, the compiler inserts padding because it is a requirement by the architecture or because it allows faster access. Anyway, the size can't be specified without specifying an implementation.

Comment: Which uses the least? How about you use `sizeof` and find out (for that compiler)?

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Comment: The class that the compiler has arranged the members such that it uses the least amount of padding. Which one that is [or if they are indeed all the same - which is one valid option according to the C++ standard], depends on the architecture of the processor. There are also some variations not listed above that under some circumstances would use less memory, possibly.

Comment: Good luck with your job hunting, as I expect this is an "interview/test for job application" question.

Comment: @chris, because it's not compiler specific. It's asking in general, which uses the least? I know it's quite ambiguous in what it's asking, but it hasn't mentioned a specific compiler at all!

@ GWW, thanks, handy! 

@ Mats Not quite! It's part of last year's Search for a Star test paper (consists of 3 rounds, of those who passed the first (the test) last year, 75% were offered placements), we have the 2013 one on Wednesday!

Either way, was just curiosity. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MSVC2010 I get

A = 16 bytes
B = 12 bytes
C = 16 bytes
D = 16 bytes

this is probably due to alignment of the different types. Since char and bool are both small they share a DWORD.

However this is compiler and platform independent. There is nothing stopping a compiler implementer from making them all the same size or making a char 64 bytes or whatever. The requirements of the standard are quite lax about this kind of thing.

Comment: They appear to have been quite lazy when asking the question I suppose. As others said (and as my coursemates and I said), they should have given a compiler really. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer E, this one :-)

```
class E
{
    float duration;
    char code;
    int count;
    bool enabled;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Nothing can be said for other examples, it really depends of the compiler, arch, ...